# Use gstreamer restream without re-encoding?

Tags: gstreamer

I would like to send an rtsp h264 stream over udp without transcoding. These pipeline doesn't work:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/steam  name=demux demux. ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mux. demux. ! queue ! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse ! queue ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux alignment=7 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.1 port=5002
```

```
...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpSsrcDemux:rtpssrcdemux1.GstPad:rtcp_src_560534233: caps = application/x-rtcp, ssrc=(uint)560534233
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer1.GstPad:sink_rtcp: caps = application/x-rtcp, ssrc=(uint)560534233
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpSsrcDemux:rtpssrcdemux0.GstPad:rtcp_src_164951109: caps = application/x-rtcp, ssrc=(uint)164951109
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0.GstPad:sink_rtcp: caps = application/x-rtcp, ssrc=(uint)164951109
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0: ts-offset = 119978681
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0: ts-offset = 80018388
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0: ts-offset = 119978931
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0: ts-offset = 79926621
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:demux/GstRtpBin:manager/GstRtpJitterBuffer:rtpjitterbuffer0: ts-offset = 119935374
0:00:00.0 / 99:99:99.
```

I managed to send audio and video streams separately.These pipelines work:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/steam ! rtph264depay ! h264parse  ! mpegtsmux alignment=7 ! queue ! udpsink host=192.168.1.1 port=5002 sync=false
```

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/steam ! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse  ! mpegtsmux alignment=7 ! queue ! udpsink host=host=192.168.1.1 port=5002 sync=false
```

Thanks in advance !